# Java Multithreading and Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A implements Runnable  
class B extends A
```

Under these circumstances `B` **IS A** `Runnable`.

Is it valid to write:

```
class B extends A implements Runnable
```

If it is valid, will the `run` method in `B` override that of `A`?
What could be the possible scenarios?
I'm uh confused...

Comment: This question is not about multithreading. `Runnable` instances don't *have* to run in separate threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class B extends A implements Runnable
```

is valid Java syntax, but doesn't really do anything. By extending A, B is Runnable.

When the run method is called on an A object, A's run method will be called. When run is called on a B object, A's run method will be called unless B overrides A's run method

Consider the following:

```
class A implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
          System.out.println("A's run method");
    }
}

class B extends A implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
          System.out.println("B's run method");
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       A obj1 = new A();
       A obj2 = new B();
       B obj3 = new B();
       Runnable obj4 = new A();
       Runnable obj5 = new B();

       obj1.run(); // prints "A's run method"
       obj2.run(); // prints "B's run method"
       obj3.run(); // prints "B's run method"
       obj4.run(); // prints "A's run method"
       obj5.run(); // prints "B's run method"

    }
}
```

Comment: What if I do the following: Thread t1 = new Thread(new A()); Thread t2 = new Thread(new B()); t1.start(); t2.start();

Comment: @Kevin: Exactly the same. Multi-threading has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The same. The thread from t1 will print “A’s run method”, the thread from t2 will print “B’s run method”.

Comment: @Bombe
@Jesper
But doesn't the run in B override the run in A, then both the runs should print "B's run method"

Comment: Kevin - when you do "new A()", you've created an instance of A, not B.

Comment: This means when you do A.run(), it executes the code defined in the A class.  B's overriding does not mean it replaces all the parent class' definitions for run().

Answer (score 6):

Since "`implements Runnable`" doesn't introduce any executable code into a class but is basically just a promise to implement the necessary methods, repeating "`implements Runnable`" on a class that already extends another class that implements `Runnable` does effectively nothing.

There is a very slight difference that can be seen when using reflection, but other than that there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid as interfaces only define that a method exists. B.run will override that of A, same as if B did not implement Runnable directly or if A did not implement Runnable but did have a public void run() method.

Answer (score 2):

Its enough to write

```
class B extends A
```

Class A already implements runnable so extending it makes this runnable too. To do something specific to class B override run() in class B.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by extending A, you are already implementing `Runnable`, so you simply need to override the `run()` method and all will be well in Mordor.

If you don't, the superclasses `run()` will take effect.